# ASIHTTPRequest responseData null

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, response, nsdata

I'm working with ASIHTTPRequest but I have a responseData empty.
The response is supposed to be a JSON response and when I try to do this in the browser, it works perfectly.

Here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)simpleURLFetch {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/url/url"];
    ASIHTTPRequest* request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.timeOutSeconds = 30;
    [request setDelegate:self]; // I correctly set the ASIHTTPRequestDelegate in my .h file
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)azrequest {
    NSString *responseString = [azrequest responseString];
    NSData *responseData = [azrequest responseData];

    NSLog(@"repo : %@ / %@", responseData, responseString);
}
```

And the log displayed this : "repo : (null) / <> /"

Maybe, I'm not using the result with the good way.. Is there a solution to have my JSON response ?

Regards,
Sébastien ;)

Comment: Have you confirmed that your URL is generating good JSON response?

Comment: Yes, I do. I try on my browser and it works perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not getting data back, not that you're accessing the data incorrectly. The URL in your code is clearly invalid, and I suspect that's not the one you're using. Either way, the request fails to get any data, so there's nothing to log.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented the delegate method:
-(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

Then, responseData will be null. Because the API will handover the data handling to the application.